# Openpyxl version 2.5.11 issue

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I updated yesterday with Openpyxl library to version 2.5.11. Now, when i simply open an excel workbook (it's a xlsx file without macros), I get the following strange error message that I didn't have when I was opening the exact same file yesterday before I updated the library:
Code:

```
tips = r"NTipsPerf6b.xlsm"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(tips)
```

and this is the traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-980c37a8c9f7> in <module>()
----> 1 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(tips)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py in load_workbook(filename, read_only, keep_vba, data_only, guess_types, keep_links)
    291         ws._rels = [] # reset
    292 
--> 293     parser.assign_names()
    294 
    295     #wb._differential_styles.styles =  [] # tables may depened upon dxf

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\workbook.py in assign_names(self)
    104             reserved = defn.is_reserved
    105             if reserved in ("Print_Titles", "Print_Area"):
--> 106                 sheet = self.wb._sheets[defn.localSheetId]
    107                 if reserved == "Print_Titles":
    108                     rows, cols = _unpack_print_titles(defn)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

if anyone has any clue on how to fix it that would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Submit a bug report with a sample file.

Comment: @Charlie Clark where / how?

Comment: Also, I'm sharing this information from my office. It's a miracle I can post data here, I won't be allowed to do it in other website due to internal restrictions. All I can share is the information above, it seems evident there's a bug in this library version.

Comment: And how do you expect the bug to be identified and fixed without a relevant file?

Comment: I mean it's an excel file with different data and chart sheets. you have the traceback so you can see where the code get stuck. How can it be even possible that by simply loading/opening a file I get an index out of range error?

Comment: That's not the point. I never said it's easy but I said you have a clear hint in what's going wrong. You can't expect people to share their files with you every time you need to trouble shoot the code. Then if this offended you, I'm sorry, that was not my intention. openpyxl it's a fantastic library.